# Best approach for including bits of Javascript on individual pages in Sitefinity

Tags: javascript, sitefinity

Frequently, I just want to drop a bit of jQuery on an individual page.  Given my early understanding of Sitefinity, I think...

1. I can't easily put JS in the <head>.
2. I could put JS in a Generic Content control, but then my JS is sitting inline in the <body>.  Maybe I need to relax, but I don't usually like to put much JS in the <body>.

It feels like this kind of scenario is an afterthought.  Is JS a 2nd-class citizen in Sitefinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript does not live in the head. Yahoo even [says](http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/07/high_performanc_5.html) it is better for performance

Answer (score 2):

I agree with epascarello you really shouldn't be putting your javascript in the head anyway.

And just in case you didn't know about this the [jQuery framework is part of Sitefinity](http://blogs.sitefinity.com/GeorgiChokov/Posts/09-03-25/How_to_use_jQuery_and_other_JavaScript_Libraries_in_Sitefinity.aspx).  The article also shows you how you can include external libraries in sitefinity from anywhere withing your project whether it be master page or user control.

Comment: Sean is correct.  JQuery is included with Sitefinity and certainly not a 2nd-citizen.  It's used heavily by Sitefinity itself.  The blog post Sean linked above pertains to Sitefinity 3.x.  A Sitefinity 4.x version of this post can be found here - http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/gabesumner/posts/11-09-01/how_to_use_jquery_and_other_javascript_libraries_in_sitefinity.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Why not have the jQuery code in a separate .js file and use unobtrusive JavaScript?  With jQuery you can separate behavior and markup so nicely that you should never have to include JavaScript in your head or body ever again.

Just use the standard onLoad function in jQuery and put all of your initialization code in there.

Try it, I think that you will like it!  If you like using CSS for separation of presentation and markup, then jQuery can do the same thing with behavior and markup.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but one way you can do it now is:

Add a Javascript block (under Scripts & Styles), and then paste the URL to the jquery code:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js
```

Then add another Javascript block with your jquery, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("hello");
});
```

Or you can also paste the URL to your js file.